# How to remove tranform:trainsition(); from inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I am doing drag and drop to the box. after droping the box. it is diverted from dropped position. as after inspecting i can see transform: translate(100px, 90px). can you guys help me out. i am stuck.

I have tried  `style="transform: none";`

After incepting element in brower : `style="top: 8px; left: 92px; width: 70px; height: 80px; transform: translate(-100px, -16px);"`

i want to remove transform: `translate(-100px, -16px)`: or it should not be added. with my style

Comment: Can't say much without code but one thing you can do is add class on drop, with transform:none ! important so it will overide those inline style

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably it's not the best solution but you can use:

```
transform: none !important;
```